# Bucketing data with R

Tags: r, dataframe, bucket

I have some data in R stored in a data.frame that looks like this:

```
time     value
53       5
55       5
59       7
61       9
79       6
118      11
200      5
```

I would like to bucket my data by time, making buckets of 60 seconds (the time is in seconds). However, what I want to do is make a new data.frame that will keep only the 1st and the last entry of each bucket. I understand I can do this easily with a loop but my problem is with how to tell R to find the 1st and the last element of a bucket.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`data.table` makes this convenient.  Here, columns are added for the first and last value in each minute:

```
xt <- data.table(x)
xt[,first:=head(.SD,1), by=time %/% 60]
xt[,last:=tail(.SD,1), by=time %/% 60]
xt
##    time value first last
## 1:   53     5     5    7
## 2:   55     5     5    7
## 3:   59     7     5    7
## 4:   61     9     9   11
## 5:   79     6     9   11
## 6:  118    11     9   11
## 7:  200     5     5    5
```

Here is one easy way to trim this to the minute buckets.  Modify the `time` column so that it indicates the head of the minute, remove the `value` column, and pass to `unique`:

```
xt$time <- 60 * xt$time %/% 60
xt$value <- NULL
unique(xt)
##    time first last
## 1:    0     5    7
## 2:   60     9   11
## 3:  180     5    5
```

To get the times and values for the first and last rows in each minute, `aggregate.data.frame` works well, but you need two passes.

First values:

```
aggregate(cbind(time, value) ~ time %/% 60, data=x, FUN=head, 1)
##   time%/%60 time value
## 1         0   53     5
## 2         1   61     9
## 3         3  200     5
```

Last values:

```
aggregate(cbind(time, value) ~ time %/% 60, data=x, FUN=tail, 1)
##   time%/%60 time value
## 1         0   59     7
## 2         1  118    11
## 3         3  200     5
```

These may then be combined into the desired output.

Comment: This looks very interesting! However, what I would like to do is make a new data.frame or data.table made up of the ENTIRE line (hence I need both the value of `time` and `value` for that entry) of the 1st and last element of the bucket, rather than just the entry for `value` of the 1st and last element of the bucket.

Comment: +1, also: `xt[xt[, .I[c(1L, if (.N>=2L) .N)], by=time%/%60L]$V1]`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the times are ascending so this gives the subset of rows which are first or last in each bucket of 60 seconds.

```
subset(DF, time %in% unlist(tapply(time, time %/% 60 * 60, range)))
```

giving:

```
  time value
1   53     5
3   59     7
4   61     9
6  118    11
```